# Changes to Display Template not appearing

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, display-template

I have customized the Item_PDF Display template. I would like the hover panel that is displayed to be based on the Item_Person_Hover panel.  The goal is to present expertise information about the author of the document presented in Item_PDF.

I have changed the reference in Item_PDF to the Hover Panel as follows:

```
var hoverUrl = "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Item_Person_HoverPanel.js";
```

I've published the custom Item_PDF html and a js is created, yet the hover panel that appears continues to be the Item_PDF_HoverPanel despite the change to the reference line above.

I don't expect the hover panel to work initally, as I need to figure what data needs to be passed to it from the standard PDF template, but I thought at the very least it would appear blank or cause an error.

thanks!

Comment: go to your webpart on a page and in the display template section, select your PDF template

Comment: I was using a Result Type.  When I switched to select the Display Template there are two with the same name.  I selected each one and one of them works perfectly.  You should answer and I will mark as answered.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you are currently using a Result type.

Instead of that, switch to `Use a single template to display items` and select your display template.

If its custom, select that or if you have modified the OOTB template then select `PDF Item` display template and it will start showing up your templates with your people hover panel.

[image]

Would advise you to not modify the OOTB display templates as Microsoft can push some changes to these templates which might break your customization. Instead of that, you should make a copy of the OOTB templates, customize them and then use that in your solution.